# Getting n smallest in row in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
            A  B  C  D
date                  
2015-01-01  1  1  2  3
2015-01-02  1  2  3  3
2015-01-03  1  2  1  3
2015-01-04  3  2  1  1
2015-01-05  3  2  2  1
2015-01-06  1  1  2  3
2015-01-07  1  2  3  3
2015-01-08  1  2  1  3
2015-01-09  3  2  1  1
2015-01-10  3  2  2  1
2015-01-11  3  2  2  1
```

Basic rule: I would like to identify the 2 smallest values for each row and set the values for these to 1. The other values should be set to 0.

Additional rules:

```
1 1 1 1  should be 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2  should be 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 3  should be 1 1 1 0
1 2 3 4  should be 1 1 0 0
```

I hope you can follow the rules and for the dataframe in the beginning the result should be

```
date        A   B   C   D
2015-01-01  1   1   0   0
2015-01-02  1   1   0   0
2015-01-03  1   0   1   0
2015-01-04  0   0   1   1
2015-01-05  0   1   1   1
2015-01-06  1   1   0   0
2015-01-07  1   1   0   0
2015-01-08  1   0   1   0
2015-01-09  0   0   1   1
2015-01-10  0   1   1   1
2015-01-11  0   1   1   1
```

**EDIT**

*"Maybe you want rank with method='first' I think this would work – EdChum"*
Result for the dataframe:

```
            A  B  C  D
date                  
2015-01-01  1  2  3  4
2015-01-02  1  2  3  4
2015-01-03  1  3  2  4
2015-01-04  4  3  1  2
2015-01-05  4  2  3  1
2015-01-06  1  2  3  4
2015-01-07  1  2  3  4
2015-01-08  1  3  2  4
2015-01-09  4  3  1  2
2015-01-10  4  2  3  1
2015-01-11  4  2  3  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to extend past 4 columns perhaps you could try something like the following, the mask idea from the previous solution is the way I would also implement it, however you could specify that you want the two smallest values:

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.isin(x.nsmallest(2)), axis=1)
df[mask] = 1
df[~mask] = 0
df

            A   B   C   D
2015-01-01  1   1   0   0
2015-01-02  1   1   0   0
2015-01-03  1   0   1   0
2015-01-04  0   0   1   1
2015-01-05  0   1   1   1
2015-01-06  1   1   0   0
2015-01-07  1   1   0   0
2015-01-08  1   0   1   0
2015-01-09  0   0   1   1
2015-01-10  0   1   1   1
2015-01-11  0   1   1   1
```

I worry about performance with this solution on larger datasets, but it should get you the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

I think this does what you want:

```
In [3]:
mask = df.rank(method='dense', axis=1) <= 2
df[mask] = 1
df[~mask] = 0
df

Out[3]:
            A  B  C  D
date                  
2015-01-01  1  1  1  0
2015-01-02  1  1  0  0
2015-01-03  1  1  1  0
2015-01-04  0  1  1  1
2015-01-05  0  1  1  1
2015-01-06  1  1  1  0
2015-01-07  1  1  0  0
2015-01-08  1  1  1  0
2015-01-09  0  1  1  1
2015-01-10  0  1  1  1
2015-01-11  0  1  1  1
```

This returns a [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) of the values row-wise and passing `method='dense'` will rank according to the first time the value is seen and increments by 1 when a new group is seen, you can change the `2` to any `n` value and the ranking is independent of whether or not the values in the rows are integer and sequential or not.

Comment: Great but is it possible to get a more general solution that can handle the n:th lowest values (n=2 in the example above) and can handle more then 4 columns?

Comment: I realise this only works given the property that the total number of values in the row is equal to the size divided by `n`, a more general solution would involve using `apply` I think, but it won't be vectorised so will be slow for large dfs

Comment: Are the values always integer and from 1-4?

Comment: I think using `rank` will do what you want, see my edit

Comment: No, example is rank applied to the original dataframe, The result will be 1 to max = number of columns (but will be less if two values in a row are requal).

Comment: Maybe you want `rank` with `method='first'` I think this would work

Comment: I think you might want `rank(method="dense", axis=1)`, not `min`.  Consider `pd.Series([1,1,2,2,3])`: IIUC, the OP would want `[1,1,1,1,0]`, but `min` gives ranks of `[1,1,3,3,5]` and so we'd get `[1,1,0,0,0]`.  (Disclaimer: I implemented `dense` and so I might be biased towards its use. :-)

Comment: @DSM yes I had considered this, I think you're right (as always) for some reason I discounted due to some strange results this was probably my hacking skills